# A problem on Complex differentiability

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I following problem was given as a homework, I have explained how I approached it I need to know if it was correct and even then if it there wasn't any easier way, because that way only had tedious calculations.
Find the points in $ \Bbb C $ such that $ f(z)= \frac{(\bar Z)^2}{Z}$ when $z $ in not equal to  0 and $f(z)=0 $ when $z=0$

1)f is differentiable
2) f is analytic
3) f satisfies CR equations.

I let $z=x+iy$ and then $f(z) =  \frac{(x-iy)^3}{x^2+y^2}$

by simplifying it gave $u(x,y) =\frac{(x^3-3xy^2)}{ (x^2+y^2)} $ and $ v(x,y)=\frac{(y^3-3x^2y)}{ (x^2+y^2 )}$

where $f=u+iv$

By computing the partial derivatives 
and the equations are not statisfied at a non zero point. And I can show it is not differentiable at $0$
Therefore it is differentiable no where and analytic nowhere?

Comment: You wrote $f(z)=(x-iy)^3/x^2+y^2$, shouldn't it be $f(z)=(x-iy)^2/x^2+y^2$? Also, check your formula for $v(x,y)$, I think it has an extra $y^2$.

Comment: It is conjugate of z squared over z so wouldn't it be equal to $\bar Z^3/Z$

Comment: Oh, I see where the cube is coming from. Still, you are missing some parentheses, and it should be $f(z)=\frac{(x-iy)^3}{x^2+y^2}$, similarly for $u,v$.

Comment: yes I added the parenthesis hope it's clearer now

Comment: Your expression for $v$ should be $v = \frac{y^3-3x^2y}{x^2+y^2}.

Answer (score 1):

Fixing your typo in $v$,
I get that
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 3x^2-3y^2 = -(-3x^2 + 3y^2) = -\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$$

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}  = -6x y$$

So in a sense you get the opposite of the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Indeed the only place the original equations are satisified is at $(0,0)$.